# Almost all of a formula in \boldsymbol

Tags: math-mode, fonts, amsmath, boldmath

I would like to typeset *almost* all of a formula in bold sans-serif font using `\boldsymbol` and `\mathsf`. For example:

```
$$\boldsymbol{\mathsf{x+{}}}n\boldsymbol{\mathsf{{}=y}}$$
```

or

```
$$\boldsymbol{\mathsf{S}}^n\boldsymbol{\mathsf{0}}$$
```

[image: Output]

However, I would like to be able to do it more simply, by enclosing that parts that should be typeset normally in some sort of command. Like this:

```
$$\boldsymbol{\mathsf{x+\something{n}=y}}$$
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and define macros:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\svar}[1]{\bm{\mathsf{#1}}} % syntactic variable
\newcommand{\sfun}[1]{\bm{\mathsf{#1}}} % syntactic function

\begin{document}

Some text before the formula
\[
\svar{x}+n=\svar{y}
\]
and some text in between
\[
\sfun{S}^{n}\svar{0}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use `$$` in LaTeX, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Here is an alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\lf}[1]{\bm{#1}}
\newcommand{\var}[1]{\mathsf{#1}}
\newcommand{\meta}[1]{{\mathpalette\dometa{#1}}}
\newcommand{\dometa}[2]{\mbox{\mathversion{normal}$#1#2$}}

\begin{document}

Some text before the formula
\[
\lf{ \var{x}+\meta{n}=\var{y} }
\]
and some text in between
\[
\lf{ \var{S}^{\meta{n}}\var{0} }
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course. But I would like to be able to write $\svar{x+\something{n}=y}$. Note that the + and = signs should also be bold.

Comment: @GabrielNivasch Why should you?

Comment: Because I want very long formulas all written in bold sans-serif with some regular-font elements sprinkled in

Comment: @egreg - De gustibus non est...